# Dynamic localization in ios

Tags: ios, dynamic, localization

I know, I can localize static strings in story board and Strings in my code. But I don't have any idea on how to localize strings that I get from server. I get dynamic strings from server. Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you know which will be the string?

Comment: No I do not know the string that I will get from the server

Comment: So there is no way to do that. To localize static string in storyboards and string in code, you know the string, so you know its translate. The only way to do that is that the server localize the string.

Comment: Do you control the server? If so you could send JSON with different languages per string or even better request the string in the language you need.

Comment: my app supports almost all languages that an iphone supports. But does the sdk support receiving those strings localized by the server. For example i receive a chinese string from the webServer, will i receive the same chinese string in the response in 'connectionDidFinishLoading' delegate method? Does the sdk support this?

Comment: yes I control the server.

Comment: Then send a (JSON) request to the server asking for a specific string or a file of all those strings for a specific language. Is that possible? You can then exchange them in you app dynamically.

Comment: To answer your question above: if you handle the string encoding properly, everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this the way you should; creating multiple string files in your project.

But what you could do is find out the users language, send it to the server and receive the strings in the right language. That will mean you'll have to store multiple string files on your server.